# Need help understanding what is happening in object destructuring for React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, object-destructuring

I was watching a video about layout components and I saw that the author seemed to destructure the parameters but also assign it as a property in an object (as seen in Splitscreen.js)? I was wondering if anyone could help me understand what is going and why he chose to do this? Are there any advantages to doing so?

###### Splitscreen.js

```
export const Splitscreen = ({ left: Left, right: Right }) => {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Pane>
        <Left />
      </Pane>
      <Pane>
        <Right />
      </Pane>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

###### App.js

```
const LeftHandComponent = () => {
  return <h1>Left</h1>;
};
const RightHandComponent = () => {
  return <h1>Right</h1>;
};

function App() {
  return <Splitscreen left={LeftHandComponent} right={RightHandComponent} />;
}

export default App;
```

Comment: It allows the values to be _renamed_ to be Titlecase so they can be used as components.

Comment: @jonrsharpe THIS IS THE CORRECT ANSWER. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't some special React thing. It's <s>basic</s> JavaScript. Objects are usually destructured like this:

```js
const { age } = {
  name: "John",
  age: 23
};

console.log(age);
```

However, what if you don't want to use the given name in the object but assign it a custom name, still with object destructuring?

Remember in import statements you could do

```js
import something as smt from './something';
```

What if you wanted to call `age` `userAge`?
You can do something similar:

```js
const { age: userAge } = { age: 23 };

console.log(userAge);
```

That's what's going on. Take a regular function:

```js
function myFunc(obj) {
  console.log(obj.name);
}

myFunc({ name: "hello" });
```

You could do:

```js
function myFunc({ name }) {
  console.log(name);
}

myFunc({ name: "hello" });
```

But if you wanted to name it something else, the right hand side would rename it:

```js
function myFunc({ name: objName }) {
  console.log(objName);
}

myFunc({ name: "hello" });
```

In your example, the parameter was renamed to it's PascalCase equivalent because that's the naming convention for React components.

Answer (score -1):

Typically in HTML we use lowercase words for parameters or attributes, and an upper-case first letter for elements.  So this looks normal and correct:

```html
<Splitscreen left=xxx right=yyy>
```

It would look odd to have the parameters with an upper first letter like this:

```html
<Splitscreen Left=xxx Right=yyy>
```

Now inside of the `Splitscreen` implementation we want to use `left` and `right` as HTML elements so the author wanted to maintain the convention and call them `Left` and `Right` when using them because this would look wrong:

```html
    <Container>
      <Pane>
        <left />            <--- just looks odd
      </Pane>
      <Pane>
        <right />           <--- just looks odd
      </Pane>
    </Container>
```

Using destructuring with renaming is an easy way to assign `left` to `Left` and `right` to `Right` and avoids having bulky extra lines of code like this:

```js
export const Splitscreen = ({ left, right }) => {
  const Left = left;
  const Right = right;
  return (...)
```

Comment: It doesn't just 'look odd', it's a syntactic error to use components with a lower case first letter because they will be treated as built-in html elements, that don't exist